# How to specify Kafka AdminClientConfig (Kafka Admin api) With Trust store and Password

Tags: java, apache-kafka

How to Create Kafka AdminClientConfig (Kafka JAVA Admin api) With Trust store and Password. AdminClientConfig has method to specify AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG but How can we specify "ssl.truststore.location" and "password" property ?

If we use property file how to create AdminClientConfig with property file ?

Comment: Try the Security tutorial: https://docs.confluent.io/current/tutorials/security_tutorial.html#security-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You specify the SSL configurations for the AdminClient exactly like in the other Clients.

- Without a Properties file:

  ```java
  Properties adminProps = new Properties();
  adminProps.put(...)
  adminProps.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, "some/path/truststore");
  adminProps.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, "password");

  AdminClient admin = KafkaAdminClient.create(adminProps);
  ```
- With a Properties file:

  In `admin.properties`:

  ```
  bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
  ...
  ssl.truststore.location=some/path/truststore
  ssl.truststore.password=password
  ```

  Then in your Java code:

  ```java
  Properties adminProps = new Properties();
  adminProps.load(new FileInputStream("admin.properties"));
  AdminClient admin = KafkaAdminClient.create(adminProps);
  ```

Comment: Thank you! You might also have to specify the secure protocol, such as `adminProps.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "ssl");` :)